# How to open image.png using ps1 script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Setting the below `$usbDriveLetter` variable to automatically find the USB drive letter, and using that variable to open an image on the USB doesn't work. It literally prints "G:\image.png" in the cmd.

```
$usbDriveLetter = (gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''USB_NAME_HERE''').Name;
"$usbDriveLetter" + "image.png"
```

But if I don't use a var and make "G:\" static in the PowerShell script, the image opens just fine.

```
G:\image.png
```

So what am I doing wrong here? How do we dynamically open images using ps1 scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When combining two strings, you get a string. If you quote the path (`"G:\image.png"`) it will behave the same.

Use `Invoke-Item` to execute the path:

```
$usbDriveLetter = (gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''USB_NAME_HERE''').Name
Invoke-Item -Path ("$usbDriveLetter" + "image.png")
```

You may also use the call-operator `&`:

```
$usbDriveLetter = (gwmi win32_volume -f 'label=''USB_NAME_HERE''').Name
& ("$usbDriveLetter" + "image.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

[Frode F.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48872960/45375) provides effective solutions.

As for ***when* you need `&`**, PowerShell's *call operator*:

**In order to execute a command / open a document that is *not* specified as an *unquoted, literal string*, you need `&`**.

That is, **`&` is needed** whenever you specify the command name (or path) / document filename (or path):

- either: as a **quoted string** (e.g., `"G:\image.png"`)
- or: as the **result of an *expression*** (e.g., `("$usbDriveLetter" + "image.png")`; ditto for `$(...)`)

Note:

- In the case of **opening a *document*** (rather than invoking an executable), you may use `Invoke-Item` instead of `&`.
- If you're trying to **open a *folder path*** in File Explorer, *only* `Invoke-Item` works.

---

As for ***why* you need `&`**:

PowerShell has ***two* fundamental parsing modes**:

- ***argument* mode**, which works like traditional *shells*
- ***expression* mode**, which works like traditional *programming languages*.

Running [`Get-help about_Parsing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) provides an introduction to these modes.

In short, **it is the *first token* that determines which mode is applied**, and **in order to *execute / open* something, it must be parsed in *argument* mode** (in *expression* mode, the result is simply *output*); thus, the 1st token must be:

- either: a literal, unquoted command/document name or path, as stated.
- or: `&`, in which case the next argument - which may then be specified as a quoted string or expression - is interpreted as the command / document name or path to execute / open.